# Script do captcha só funcionando em um form somente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde,

estou tendo um problema em um codigo. na pagina contatos do site, por padrao ele traz as informações da loja matriz, porem tenho um dropdown, onde o cliente seleciona a filial desejada e o conteudo muda.

porem,

as informações estao mudando perfeitamente, mas dentro da div que esta mudando as informações tem um form, e o form esta mudando tambem, fazendo assim o codigo que captcha nao ser funcional, tem algum metodo que faz com que ele nao altere? nao sei se eu estou explicando bem..

**CODIGO**

```
<section class="main">
            <div class="drop-demo">
                <div id="dd" class="drop-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
                    <span>Selecione uma Filial</span>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a id="lojaCas" href="#">Cascavel</a></li>
                        <li><a id="lojaTol" href="#">Toledo</a></li>
                        <li><a id="lojaBel" href="#">Francisco Beltrão</a></li>
                        <li><a id="lojaFoz" href="#">Foz do iguaçu</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            ​</div>
        </section>
<div class="container_16" id="cascavel">



    <div class="grid_5">
        <div class="bg_contato">

            <span class="sub_titulo">Estamos a sua disposição!</span>

            <p class="p-class">
            Utilize o formulário para entrar em contato conosco e lhe responderemos o mais breve possível. Você também pode utilizar os contatos ao lado:</p>
        </div>

        <div class="bg_contato">
            <span class="sub_titulo">Nosso endereço</span>
            <p class="p-class">
                <b>Endereço:</b> Av. Brasil, 2255 - Cascavel/Pr<br><br>
                <b>Cep:</b> 85812-500<br><br>
                <b>Gps:</b> -25.060763,-53.397998<br><br>
                <b>Mapa:</b> <a href="https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Zeni+Motors/@-24.9551571,-53.4824516,13z/data=!4m5!1m2!2m1!1szeni+motors!3m1!1s0x94f3d48d704799d9:0x682a1a422a4fec32" target="_blank">Google Maps</a>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_5">

    <div class="bg_contato">
        <span class="sub_titulo"> Nossos contatos</span>

            <p class="p-class">
            <b>Telefones:</b>
                (45) 3218-8181  <br><br>

                <b>E-mail:</b> <a href="mailto:zenimotors@zenimotors.com">zenimotors@zenimotors.com</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    <div class="bg_contato">
        <span class="sub_titulo">Horário de Atendimento</span>

            <p class="p-class">
                <b>Segunda à Sexta</b><br>
                08:00 às 12:00<br>
                13:30 às 18:00
            <br><br>
                <b>Sábado:</b><br>
                08:30 às 12:00 h
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_6">
        <span class="sub_titulo" style="padding-left:5px">Mensagem</span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {
                $("#fone_f").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
            });
        </script>
        <form name="form-contato" id="form-contato">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Nome" id="nome">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="email">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Telefone" id="fone_f">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Cidade" id="cidade_f">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="UF" id="uf">
                </li>

                <li><textarea placeholder="Digite a sua Mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="acoes" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <div class="captcha">
                             <input class="campo" id="captchaInput" name="captchaInput" placeholder="Insira o texto ao lado" style="margin-top: -37px;margin-left: 120px;float: left;border: none;background: #F0F0F0;height: 20px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;padding: 5px;width: 120px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a id="btn_enviar" class="btn_fale" style="background: #c90909;margin-top: -37px;padding: 5px 0px;float: right;">ENVIAR</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div class="botoes-finalizar-orcamento">

            </div>

            <!-- div class="btn_contato">
                <a id="btn_enviar">Enviar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_contato">
                <a id="btn_limpar">Limpar</a>
            </div -->
        </form>
        <div id="wrapper-resposta-contato">
            <img src="images/sucesso.gif">
            <div id="msg-sucesso-contato"></div>
            <a class="btn_contato" style="margin-top:15px;margin-right:-3px;" id="voltar-para-form">VOLTAR</a>
        </div>
    </div>








    <div class="grid_16">
        <h2 class="h2-class" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">LOCALIZAÇÃO</h2>
        <iframe width="940" height="368" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d34414.80690138398!2d-53.458512278141384!3d-24.952128561184477!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0000000000000000%3A0x682a1a422a4fec32!2sZeni+Motors!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1442932056074"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container_16" id="toledo" style="display:none;">



    <div class="grid_5">
        <div class="bg_contato">

            <span class="sub_titulo">Estamos a sua disposição!</span>

            <p class="p-class">
            Utilize o formulário para entrar em contato conosco e lhe responderemos o mais breve possível. Você também pode utilizar os contatos ao lado:</p>
        </div>

        <div class="bg_contato">
            <span class="sub_titulo">Nosso endereço</span>

            <p class="p-class">
                <b>Endereço:</b> Av. Parigot de Souza, 3653 - Toledo/Pr<br><br>
                <b>Cep:</b> 85903-170<br><br>
                <b>Gps:</b>  -25.060763,-53.397998<br><br>
                <b>Mapa:</b> <a href="https://www.google.com.br/maps/place/Zeni+Motors/@-24.7200472,-53.7521059,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x94f39593499bf90b:0xb07420a1eeae8cae" target="_blank">Google Maps</a>
            </p>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_5">

    <div class="bg_contato">
        <span class="sub_titulo"> Nossos contatos</span>

            <p class="p-class">
                <b>Telefones:</b>
                (45) 3379-6600  <br><br>
                <b>E-mail:</b> <a href="mailto:zenimotors@zenimotors.com">zenimotors@zenimotors.com</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    <div class="bg_contato">
        <span class="sub_titulo">Horário de Atendimento</span>

            <p class="p-class">
                <b>Segunda à Sexta</b><br>
                08:00 às 12:00<br>
                13:30 às 18:00
            <br><br>
                <b>Sábado:</b><br>
                08:30 às 12:00 h
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid_6">
        <span class="sub_titulo" style="padding-left:5px">Mensagem</span>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                            jQuery(function($) {
                                    $("#fone_f").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
                            });
                    </script>
        <form name="form-contato" id="form-contato">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Nome" id="nome">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" id="email">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Telefone" id="fone_f">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Cidade" id="cidade_f">
                </li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="UF" id="uf">
                </li>

                <li><textarea placeholder="Digite a sua Mensagem" id="mensagem"></textarea>
                </li>
                                    <li>
                                            <div class="acoes" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                                    <div class="captcha">
                                                             <input class="campo" id="captchaInput" name="captchaInput" placeholder="Insira o texto ao lado" style="margin-top: -37px;margin-left: 120px;float: left;border: none;background: #F0F0F0;height: 20px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;padding: 5px;width: 120px;">
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <a id="btn_enviar" class="btn_fale" style="background: #c90909;margin-top: -37px;padding: 5px 0px;float: right;">ENVIAR</a>
                                    </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clear"></div>

                            <div class="botoes-finalizar-orcamento">

                            </div>

            <!-- div class="btn_contato">
                <a id="btn_enviar">Enviar</a>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_contato">
                <a id="btn_limpar">Limpar</a>
            </div -->
        </form>
        <div id="wrapper-resposta-contato">
            <img src="images/sucesso.gif">
            <div id="msg-sucesso-contato"></div>
            <a class="btn_contato" style="margin-top:15px;margin-right:-3px;" id="voltar-para-form">VOLTAR</a>
        </div>
    </div>








    <div class="grid_16">
        <h2 class="h2-class" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">LOCALIZAÇÃO</h2>

        <iframe width="940" height="368" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3624.1990081983777!2d-53.7521059!3d-24.720047200000003!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94f39593499bf90b%3A0xb07420a1eeae8cae!2sZeni+Motors!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1442933149261"></iframe>

    </div>
</div>
```